# Unit test failing: How do I properly select and click a components button

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a unit test here:

```
fit('should call getImageByID upon submit when a search id is present', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'getImageById');
    component.searchId = '1';
    submit = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#getimagebyid')).nativeElement;
    submit.click();
    expect(component.getImageById).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The unit test is failing as the expect is not met (The method is not being executed), what am I missing? Here is the component method not being triggered:

```
getImageById() {
        this.imageAPIService.getImage(this.searchId).subscribe(res => {
            this.response.id = (res as any).id;
            this.response.image = (res as any).image;
        });
    }
```

and the html for the component:

```
<h4>Browse Images</h4>
<div class="row">
    <img *ngIf="response.id != null" [src]="response.image[0].url" height="200">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchId" type="text">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="getimagebyid" [disabled]="!searchId" (click)="getImageById(searchId)">Search</button>
</div>
```

Comment: More broadly than your specific question, you shouldn't be mocking out parts of the component you're trying to test. Inject a mock `imageAPIService` and make sure its `getImage` method is invoked with the correct value - mock collaborators and test behaviour. This lets you control when the observable emits as well, using a subject. I wrote a blog post on testing: see https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/16/async-angular-tests.html, there's also guidance in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, but you will need to wait for the click event to be processed before checking if the method has been called.

1) The most direct way to do it is to call [detectChanges()](https://angular.io/guide/testing#componentfixture-methods) to explicitly activate change detection.

```
it('clicking on settings icon will trigger openModal method', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'getImageById');
  component.searchId = '1';
  submit = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#getimagebyid')).nativeElement;
  submit.click();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.getImageById).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

2) Alternatively, you may use [automatic change detection](https://angular.io/guide/testing#automatic-change-detection) on your .spec file.

```
 import { ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, . . . . } from '@angular/core/testing';
.
.
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ BannerComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true }
  ]
});
```

3) Handle it by using the [async()](https://angular.io/guide/testing#async-test-with-async) functionality to handle the asynchronous button clicking event. This is followed by calling `.whenStable()`, which returns the promise.

```
import { async, . . . . } from '@angular/core/testing';
.
.
it('clicking on settings icon will trigger openModal method', async(() => {
  spyOn(component, 'getImageById');
  component.searchId = '1';
  submit = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#getimagebyid')).nativeElement;
  submit.click();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.getImageById).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution I can think of is:

```
it('should call getImageByID upon submit when a search id is present', () => {
  const spy = spyOn(component, 'getImageById');
  fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#getimagebyid'))
    .triggerEventHandler('click', null);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where `submit.click()` was only sometimes executing the button's click handler. Changing to this approach turned out to be more reliable:

```
submit = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#getimagebyid')).nativeElement;
submit.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```